# Define the CMake object-file directory on a per-configuration basis

Tags: cmake

Intermediate object files always get built in the same directory (which for me defaults to `CMakeFiles/<target>.dir/`). Is it possible to make this directory configuration-dependent? That would save me from recompiling all the object files every time I switch configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use separate build tree for each build configuration instead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfectly sense.